# I am trying to run a python script from inside a very simple Docker container. The script runs as expected on my machine, but not on the container

Tags: python, docker

First, I'll post the Python script:

```
import os
import re
import statistics
from collections import defaultdict


def read_file():
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    file_path = f"{cwd}/SensorLog.txt"
    reference_temp = 0
    reference_humidity = 0
    current_sensor_name = ""
    sensors = defaultdict(list)
    with open(file_path) as file:
        for row in file.readlines():
            reference = re.search(r"^reference temp +(\d+.?\d*) +humidity +(\d+.?\d*)$", row)
            if reference:
                reference_temp = float(reference.group(1))
                reference_humidity = float(reference.group(2))
            current_sensor = re.search(r"^(?:(?:temperature .*)|(?:humidity .*))$", row)
            if current_sensor:
                current_sensor_name = current_sensor.group()
            value = re.search(r"(?<= )\d{1,5}.\d{1,4}(?=\n)$", row)
            if value and current_sensor_name:
                sensors[current_sensor_name].append(value.group())

        return reference_temp, reference_humidity, sensors

def rate(key, reference_temp, reference_humidity, stdev, mean):
    result = ''
    if 'temperature' in key:
        reference = reference_temp
        if abs(reference-mean) <= 0.5:
            if stdev < 3:
                result = 'is ultra-precise'
            if stdev < 5:
                result = 'is very precise'
        if not result:
            result = 'is precise'
    if 'humidity' in key:
        reference = reference_humidity
        if abs(reference-mean) <= 0.01:
            result = 'is precise'
        else:
            result = 'is discarded'
    return result


def main():
    reference_temp, reference_humidity, sensors = read_file()
    result = dict()
    for key, values in sensors.items():
        float_values = list(map(float, values))
        stdev = statistics.stdev(float_values)
        mean = statistics.mean(float_values)
        result[key] = rate(key, reference_temp, reference_humidity, stdev, mean)
    print(result)


main()
```

When I run this on my computer, it prints a dictionary full of the information I'm expecting to see, properly sorted. I tried copying the script and the file it's supposed to process to a plain Docker container, with the intent that the python script would run automatically, and all I get printed to the console when the Docker container runs is a pair of empty curly brackets containing nothing. I'll post the Dockerfile next:

```
FROM python:3

COPY "./sensor.py" "./SensorLog.txt" ./

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "./sensor.py"]
```

Like I said, very simple. I opened a bash shell into the container, and SensorLog.txt is there, and when I run 'cat' on it, it contains the same information as on my computer. I suspect the problem is related to my using `os.getcwd()` but I'm honestly not sure what the workaround should be. Just in case, here is the contents of the text file, as found on my computer and when running cat in the container, as well:

> reference temp 70.0 humidity 45.0
> temperature thermometer-1
> 2007-04-05T22:00 72.4
> 2007-04-05T22:01 76.0
> 2007-04-05T22:02 79.1
> 2007-04-05T22:03 75.6
> 2007-04-05T22:04 71.2
> 2007-04-05T22:05 71.4
> 2007-04-05T22:06 69.2
> 2007-04-05T22:07 65.2
> 2007-04-05T22:08 62.8
> 2007-04-05T22:09 61.4
> 2007-04-05T22:10 64.0
> 2007-04-05T22:11 67.5
> 2007-04-05T22:12 69.4
> temperature thermometer-2
> 2007-04-05T22:01 69.5
> 2007-04-05T22:02 70.1
> 2007-04-05T22:03 71.3
> 2007-04-05T22:04 71.5
> 2007-04-05T22:05 69.8
> humidity hygrometer-1
> 2007-04-05T22:04 45.2
> 2007-04-05T22:05 45.3
> 2007-04-05T22:06 45.1
> humidity hygrometer-2
> 2007-04-05T22:04 44.4
> 2007-04-05T22:05 43.9
> 2007-04-05T22:06 44.9
> 2007-04-05T22:07 43.8
> 2007-04-05T22:08 42.1
> temperature thermometer-3
> 2007-04-05T22:00 70.4
> 2007-04-05T22:01 70.0
> 2007-04-05T22:02 72.1
> 2007-04-05T22:03 71.6
> 2007-04-05T22:04 72.2
> 2007-04-05T22:05 70.4
> 2007-04-05T22:06 69.2
> 2007-04-05T22:07 70.2

EDIT 9/13/21 On the advice of @Steve Trotta I edited the Dockerfile thusly:

```
FROM python:3

RUN mkdir -p "/var/env/script"

COPY "./sensor.py" "./SensorLog.txt" "/var/env/script"

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "/var/env/script/sensor.py"]
```

Now, when running the container, I get this error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/var/env/script/sensor.py", line 70, in  main()
> File "/var/env/script/sensor.py", line 59, in main reference_temp, reference_humidity, sensors = read_file()
> File "/var/env/script/sensor.py", line 14, in read_file with open(file_path) as file: FileNotFoundError:
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '//SensorLog.txt'

And yet, when I open a bash shell into that same container, and runt he script in that folder, it works just fine, populating a filled dict just as on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a:

RUN mkdir /path/to/some/folder

then change your COPY command to:

COPY "./sensor.py" "./SensorLog.txt" /path/to/some/folder

then change your final line to:

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "path/to/some/folder/sensor.py"]

That would make it easier to diagnose, I would imagine, and I think you're onto something with the working directory comment.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so, after continuing to fiddle with it, here is the solution that worked, I changed the Dockerfile to read this:

```
FROM python:3

RUN mkdir -p "/var/env/script"

COPY "./sensor.py" "./SensorLog.txt" /var/env/script

WORKDIR "/var/env/script"

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "sensor.py"]
```

This solved my problems, and the python script runs automatically when the container starts and prints a populated dict as expected.